# Why does IntelliJ show some numbers in gray with underscores in the middle just to "fix it" when clicked?

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea

This is a .sql file when opened with Postgresql dialect, and it shows the number 200000 as 200_000 in gray.

Upon clicking it it "fixes it" by turning it into 200000...

The top part of the image shows the same file in NP++,

where it does indeed not have an underscore to begin with...

So what on earth is this for?

[image: Same file shown in notepad++]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is meant to make large numbers more easy to read. You can disable it in `Preferences | Editor | General | Code Folding` under the `SQL` header, using the option named `Put underscores in numeric numerals (6-digit or longer)`. This option will be [disabled by default](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-10205) in version 2021.1 of IntelliJ IDEA and related IDEs.